# Plot regression line of a linear mixed model taking into account other variables and random effects?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, lme4

I have a model with several fixed and random variables.
Here is the code:

```
model1<-lmer(dep ~ pred + sex + age + heat + (1|ID) + (1|year),data=data)
```

So, by running a ggplot I get this graph

[image: ggplot dep & pred]

However, the ggplot, and the `geom_smooth()` function will only plot the slope and confidence intervals calculated between `dep` and `pred`.
**But it will not take into account the other factors, including random terms**

Indeed, with the code
`Effect("pred",model1)`

I get a different and probably real slope

```
pred effect

        600        1000        2000        3000        4000 
-0.14747707 -0.10876855 -0.01199725  0.08477404  0.18154534
```

Is there a way to plot the slope and the real confidence interval area of a `lmer`?

**UPDATE:** I was able to get a graph with the good coordinates and confidence intervals using `plot(effect("pred",model1))`
And this is how looks like:

[image: new plot right coordinates]

But how can I now make this graph look decent? Or how can I plot this in ggplot or similar so that I can modify everything?

Comment: a very similar question was asked recently see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61288690/visualising-linear-mixed-model-in-r/61289768#61289768 hope this helps. Let me know if you need guidance, don't forget to ping me otherwise I won't be notified)

Comment: @Tjebo thanks for your answer. I meant something different. I want only one single regression line between dep&pred, as in the plot above. However, I am not able to get the same slope and confidence intervals in ggplot.

Comment: best would be to provide some sample data! The way to go in ggplot would be to predict() your data, and use the error intervals as upper and lower boundary for geom_ribbon.